# Prove that all $k$-uniform hypergraphs $H$ with $e(H) \leq \frac{4^{k-1}}{3^{k}}$ admit a rainbow 4-colouring

Tags: probability, solution-verification, coloring, probabilistic-method, hypergraphs

I’m trying to apply the probabilistic method on this problem, and I’d like some checking on my solution.

> We say a $4$-colouring of the vertices of a $k$-uniform hypergraph is *rainbow* if every edge has all four colours represented. Prove that all $k$-uniform hypergraphs $H$ with $$e(H) \leq \frac{4^{k-1}}{3^{k}}$$ admit a rainbow $4$-colouring.  Here, $e(H)$ denotes the number of edges of $H$.

> **Proof:** Consider a random $4$-colouring of $H$, and let $e$ be any edge in $H$. We have:
> $$\begin{align}\text{Pr}(e \text{ is not rainbow}) &= 4 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^k = 4^{1-k}\\
> \Rightarrow \text{Pr}(H \text{ is not rainbow}) &= \text{Pr}(\text{ at least one edge is not rainbow})\\& \leq 4^{1-k} \cdot e(H) \leq \frac{1}{3^k} < 1\,.\end{align}$$
> So there is a $4$-coloring of $H$ that is a rainbow coloring.

I feel like my proof is missing some point, as it doesn’t use much of the fact that “$3^k$” appears in the bound for $e(H)$. But I can’t see how the reasoning doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct, except this:
$$\mathbb{P}(e\text{ is not rainbow})=4\,\left(\frac{\color{red}3}{4}\right)^k=\frac{{\color{red}{3^k}}}{4^{k-1}}\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\mathbb{P}(H\text{ is not rainbow})\leq e(H)\cdot\frac{{\color{red}{3^k}}}{4^{k-1}}\,{\color{red}\leq} \,1\,.$$
It takes a bit more to conclude that $$\mathbb{P}(H\text{ is not rainbow})\,\color{blue}{<}\,1\,.\tag{*}$$

If there are at least two edges in $H$, say, $e$ and $e'$, then $$\mathbb{P}(e\text{ and }e'\text{ are not rainbow})>0\,.$$  Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}(H\text{ is not rainbow})\leq 1-\mathbb{P}(e\text{ and }e'\text{ are not rainbow})\,\color{blue}{<}\,1\,.$$
If $e(H)=0$, then the claim is vacuously true.  If $e(H)=1$, then $k\geq 5$, which means $$4^{k-1}>3^k\,,$$ so $e(H)=1<\dfrac{4^{k-1}}{3^k}$, and (*) is true.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve just realized “$4 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^k$” is the probability that $e$ is monochromatic, not “not rainbow”.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the expression: $$\mathbb{P}(H\text{ is not rainbow})\leq 1-\mathbb{P}(e\text{ and }e'\text{ are not rainbow})$$

Comment: @ensbana Let's write $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_r$ for all the edges of $H$.  Then the event $E$ that $H$ is not rainbow is the union of the events $E_i:=\big\{e_i\text{ is not rainbow}\big\}$.  Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}(E)\leq \mathbb{P}(E_1\cup E_2)+\mathbb{P}(E_3)+\mathbb{P}(E_4)+\ldots+\mathbb{P}(E_r)\,.$$  As $$\mathbb{P}(E_1\cup E_2)=\mathbb{P}(E_1)+\mathbb{P}(E_2)-\mathbb{P}(E_1\cap E_2)\,,$$ we get $$\mathbb{P}(E)\leq \sum_{i=1}^r\,\mathbb{P}(E_i)-\mathbb{P}(E_1\cap E_2)\,.$$  You already know $\sum\limits_{i=1}^r\,\mathbb{P}(E_i)\leq 1$, so $$\mathbb{P}(E)\leq 1-\mathbb{P}(E_1\cap E_2)\,.$$